# Linear least squares with a polynomial activation

Tags: regression, least-squares

I might not be using the correct terms, will be grateful for explanations and directions to relevant sources.

When running linear least squares, we look for the weight vector $\vec{w}$ whose weights will minimize the term $||A\vec{w} - \vec{b}||$, where $A$'s row vectors are the training set feature vectors and $\vec{b}$ is the GT column vector. Suppose that we achieve that using the pseudo-inverse algorithm.

As a result, given a feature vector $\vec{v}$ and our optimized learned vector $\vec{w}$, the inner product $\vec{v} \cdot \vec{w}$ should linearly predict a value according to how we trained our model $\vec{w}$.

But suppose that we want instead to train a linear regression model to predict values by computing the following **non-linear** term: $(\vec{v} \cdot \vec{w} + 1)^2$. So now we want to minimize $||(A\vec{w} + 1)^2 - \vec{b}||$, which is no longer a linear problem.

I think my optimization background is not strong enough to understand - will replacing the GT vector $\vec{b}$ by the vector $\vec{(\sqrt{b})-1}$ do the work? Will it find an optimal vector $\vec{w}$ that will minimize $||(A\vec{w} + 1)^2 - \vec{b}||$ by solving the linear least-squares problem for $||A\vec{w} - (\vec{(\sqrt{b})-1})||$?

Comment: The equation $(\vec{a}\cdot\vec{x} - 1)^2 \approx b$ has *two* solutions for $(\vec{a}\cdot\vec{x}-1)$: one positive and one negative. Why are you looking for an equivalent linear formulation? As long as the optimization criterion is a (squared) Euclidean distance, you can use the Levenbarg-Marquardt algorithm to find a solution. Side note: your notation mgth be confusing for most readers, because usually $\vec{x}$ denotes the feature vector and not the model parameters.

Comment: What is a "GT vector"?

Comment: @whuber GT stands for ground-truth. It is as same as the labels vector, which is the vector of expected outputs, given the inputs as row vectors in A.

Comment: I am having trouble understanding what distinction you are trying to make with that term.  What would a non-GT vector be and how would such things change your problem, if at all?  And I don't understand "expected outputs," either: don't your data consist of *observed* responses, rather than "expected" ones?  Although this might sound like quibbling, it's motivated by wanting to make sure that readers understand your question as you intend it.  Often, the meaning of a statistical question hinges on seemingly trivial distinctions.

Comment: @whuber I asked the question from an ML point of view and my question is related to optimization.

Comment: That much is evident and unfortunately it doesn't make anything any clearer.

Comment: I think I just understood what you meant. When I wrote expected responses, I meant observed responses. I didn't notice I was using a statistics keyword that could be misleading.